# Proportion number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

We're writting a stocktake system where we need to say if there is a difference between Expected Quantities and Counted Quantity then we need to proportion the difference into records using integers. For example:

Exepected:

```
Item    |  Quantity  |  Shelf
Banana  |  2         |  1
Banana  |  1         |  2
Banana  |  2         |  3
```

Counted: 9 in total. We need to proportion the 9 out (in whole banana's) across the 3 records, giving:

```
Item    |  Quantity  |  Shelf
Banana  |  4         |  1
Banana  |  2         |  2
Banana  |  3         |  3
```

The final quantities should be approximately the same proportions as the original, and always in whole bananas. No negative bananas can exist, but records can end up with 0.

The above is just as an example. If different quantities exist the results should be similar.

We tried:

```
Ceiling(CountedQty * Expected/OriginalTotal) WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1
FLOOR(CountedQty * Expected/OriginalTotal) WHERE ROWNUMBER > 1
```

but this doesn't work when CountedQty - OriginalTotal > 2.

Previously this has been done in C# using a loop and keeping a running total which we are trying to avoid due to business requirements.

Comment: Need more clarification of your proportioning rule. Why 4,2,3 not 3,2,4 bananas? It's still proportional right?

Comment: 3,2,4 would also be fine. 3,3,3 would be wrong

Comment: Use your `FLOOR()` expression for `ROWNUMBER > 1`. Then set row 1 to `Counted-SUM(Quantity) WHERE ROWNUMBER > 1` to get the rest.

Comment: @Barmar That is a great answer. Can you post it as an answer? Also for bonus points is it possible to write the SQL to only pass once? Or do you have to have 2 update statements?

Comment: I don't really know SQL Server syntax, I'm a MySQL user. I'm pretty sure you can't do it in one pass unless you use a looping construct, because you don't know how all the rounding of the other rows will work out until it's done.

Comment: No worries. That's what we thought. if you want to post your original comment as an answer then I'll accept that

Comment: Can be same `Shelf` multiple times? Or `Shelf` number is unique

Comment: @Justin I'd assume that you'd have only one count of Bananas on a shelf but it might have a count of Coconuts on the shelf also?

Comment: @Justin, James is right. One count of banana on each shelf. Could be other types of food on the same shelf